# How to update the single property from array of object using setState (with a class component)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an array of objects in this.state, and I am trying to update the single property from the array of objects.

**This is my object**

```
 this.state = {
  persons: [
    { name: "name1", age: 1 },
    { name: "name2", age: 2 },
    { name: "name3", age: 3 }
  ],
  status: "Online"
};
```

**and i tried to update the persons[0].name**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";     
class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          persons: [
            { name: "John", age: 24 },
            { name: "Ram", age: 44 },
            { name: "Keerthi", age: 23 }
          ],
          status: "Online"
        };
      }
      changeName() {
        console.log(this);
        this.setState({
         persons[0].name: "sdfsd"
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
        <button onClick={this.changeName.bind(this)}>change name</button>
        );
      }
    }
```

am getting an error.

Comment: If you could show more code or an example it would be ideal because with this snippet of code we don't have much information...

Comment: @john_ny why do you choice the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using dot operator we can achieve this.

```
    let persons = [...this.state.persons]
persons[0].name= "updated name"
this.setState({ persons })
```

Comment: Why's this new answer that like my answer accepted?

Answer (score 5):

You should code:

```
let persons = [...this.state.persons]
persons[0].name= "updated name"
this.setState({ persons })
```

Answer (score 0):

Proble with that you mutate component state, below it's example of immutable changing, I recommend you to read articles about how to change react state. Or you can try to use Mobx because it supports mutability

```
changePerson(index, field, value) {
  const { persons } = this.state;

  this.setState({
    persons: persons.map((person, i) => index === i ? person[field] = value : person)
  })
}

// and you can use this method 
this.changePerson(0, 'name', 'newName')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState(state => (state.persons[0].name = "updated name", state))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some conditional check to find the required person.

```
const newPersonsData = this.state.persons.map((person)=>{
    return person.name=="name1" ? person.name="new_name" : person);
                      //^^^^^^^ can be some condition
});

this.setState({...this.state,{person:[...newPersonsData ]}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to copy the state first in temporary variable then after update that variable you can go for setState

```
let personsCopy = this.state.persons
personsCopy [0].name= "new name"
this.setState({ persons: personsCopy  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

See if that works for you.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      persons: [
        { name: "John", age: 24 },
        { name: "Ram", age: 44 },
        { name: "Keerthi", age: 23 }
      ],
      status: "Online"
    };
    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
    this.changeAge = this.changeAge.bind(this);
  }
  
  changeName(value,index) {
    this.setState((prevState)=>{
      const aux = prevState.persons;
      aux[index].name = value;
      return aux;
    });
  }
  
  changeAge(value,index) {
    this.setState((prevState)=>{
      const aux = prevState.persons;
      aux[index].age = value;
      return aux;
    });
  }
    
    render() {
      const personItems = this.state.persons.map((item,index)=>
        <React.Fragment>
          <input value={item.name} onChange={(e)=>this.changeName(e.target.value,index)}/>
          <input value={item.age} onChange={(e)=>this.changeAge(e.target.value,index)}/>
          <br/>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
      
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          {personItems}
          <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.persons)}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
      
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```